# fixed-height variable-width grid layout css

Tags: javascript, css

I want a fluid grid gallery layout but with image elements of the same height and variable width.

1. Content area is fixed width ie: 960px
2. Every row have images with same height but with variable width
3. And also rows can be different in height ie. first row can be 250px (and all elements must be also 250px) second row can be height ie 270px (and all her elements must have 270px height)

Here is an image showing how it should look:

[image: sample of required output]

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: Interesting link regarding what you're trying to achieve : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736135/how-to-build-a-flickr-justified-view-like-using-jquery/9889779#9889779

Comment: Tnx Aurélien Grimpard ..looks that this is what I need